# SQL Server throws bad SQL grammar / Invalid object name 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'

Tags: sql-server, database, spring-boot, h2

This method works fine in my spring boot application when I use the H2 database:

Method

```
 @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<PE> writer() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<PE> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<PE>();
        itemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource());
        itemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO PETABLE (TASK_ID, TASK_DESCRIPTION, ORIGINAL_DATE, POLICY_NO, BRAND_DESC, LOAN_NO, LINE_OF_BUSINESS, LAST_NAME, BUSINESS_RULE, BUSINESS_RULE_DESC) VALUES (:taskid, :taskdescription, :originaldate, :policyno, :branddescription, :loannumber, :lineofbusiness, :lastname, :businessrule, :businessruledescription)");
        itemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<PE>());
        return itemWriter;
    }
```

But it throw the bad SQL grammar / Invalid object name 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' error when I use SQL Server. I created the PETABLE in SQL Server manually.

SQL Server database config:

```
   @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:sqlserver://termineserver:1433;databaseName=termineserverdatabase");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("***");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("***");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
```

H2 database config:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder embeddedDatabaseBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return embeddedDatabaseBuilder.addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-h2.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:petable.sql")
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .build();
    }
```

Table creation

```
CREATE TABLE PETABLE  (
    TASK_ID VARCHAR(10),
    TASK_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500),
    ORIGINAL_DATE VARCHAR(100) ,
    POLICY_NO VARCHAR(100),
    BRAND_DESC VARCHAR(100),
    LOAN_NO VARCHAR(100),
    LINE_OF_BUSINESS VARCHAR(100),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    BUSINESS_RULE VARCHAR(100),
    BUSINESS_RULE_DESC VARCHAR(100)
) ;
```

Error when using MS-SQL database:

```
2021-03-04 13:25:00 ERROR  - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:234)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:688)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:756)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.mtb.stc.StcApplication.perform(StcApplication.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:467)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:409)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:331)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I think you need to create the Spring tables first https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/schema-appendix.html#exampleDDLScripts

Comment: this fixed the problem .. thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create all the tables that are needed to spring batch.